# screen.debug() in the @testing-library/react gives "Unexpected debug statement"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I was trying to use debug() but it gives error in the console as:
"Unexpected debug statement" what is the problem here?

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { userEvent } from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Home from './Home';
import App from './App';


test("Home input test",  () => {
  render(<Home />)
  const Field = screen.getByLabelText(/HOME/i);
  userEvent.type(Field, 'User'); 
  screen.debug();
});
```

Comment: Can you show the full error stack?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. It is just an ESlint warning. It warns you that you have some code that will print out some stuff on console while you are running the tests.

You can disable it. [from here](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-debugging-utils.md)

> You can control which debugging utils are checked for with the
> utilsToCheckFor option:
>
> ```
> {
>   "testing-library/no-debugging-utils": [
>       "error",
>       {
>           "utilsToCheckFor": {
>               "debug": false,
>               "logRoles": true,
>               "logDOM": true
>           }
>       }
>   ]
> }
> ```

or place this on top of line

```
 //eslint-disable-next-line
```